# Unable to delete rows from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

I am programming in C#. The program is about rows for a student associated with. I have list of student names and I am going to use only one student iD and print all of its grades in Data grid View. I am  not able to do that and it's just showing me all student grades. All I need is printing specifically only grades of a student.

```
   private BindingList<StudentGrade> _studentGrade = new BindingList<StudentGrade>();

    public frmGrades(int studentID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadItemsFromFiles();

        dgvGrades.DataSource = _studentGrade;

        string id = studentID.ToString();

        for (int z = 0; z < dgvGrades.Rows.Count;z++)
        {
            if (!dgvGrades.Rows[z].Cells["StudentID"].Value.ToString().Equals(id))
            {
                dgvGrades.Rows.RemoveAt(z);
                z--;
                dgvGrades.Refresh();
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to modify the collection while iterating the same; what you can do is delete the rows from the binding source and bind it again: ie.,

```
// collecting rows that satisfies the condition
var query = _studentGrade.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("StudentID") == id );

//deleting collected rows from the source
foreach(var row in query.ToList())
   row.Delete();

// re assign the datasource
dgvGrades.DataSource = _studentGrade;
dgvGrades.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove elements from grid or list. In such cases you can use filtering. You can filter input list using linq and set filtered result as `DataSource` of `DataGridView`:

```
var filteredBindingList = new BindingList<StudentGrade>(
                             _studentGrade.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentID).ToList());
dgvGrades.DataSource = filteredBindingList;
```